# Secure rethinkdb http admin interface with let's encrypt certificate

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to secure the rethinkdb http admin interface with a certificate created by let's encrypt. Therefore I added

```
http-tls-key=/path/privkey.pem
http-tls-cert=/path/cert.pem
```

to my instance1.conf. If I restart the instance, it only says

```
rethinkdb: instance1: Waiting for instance to stop (pid 13693) .... Stopped.
rethinkdb: instance1: Starting instance. (logging to `/var/lib/rethinkdb/instance1/data/log_file')
```

but it doesn't start and the log file remains empty. I'm starting the instance via init.d script. The key files are readable by the rethinkdb user. I think maybe the fullchain.pem is missing but I don't see an option for specifing it for the http admin, there are only options for the driver and the cluster: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/config-file/

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

is your either cert and key okey ?
because if you're copying from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/*` directly, it's seems everyting just symlink.

so, you need to read for the actual file
`readlink -f /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/*`

then just copythem to your `rethinkdb_cert` directory

```
mkdir $PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert
cp /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com/* $PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert/.
```

or just declare directly where those certificate files belong

```
http-tls-key=$PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert/privkey.pem
http-tls-cert=$PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert/cert.pem
```

make sure what the actually file are...,
are they have right permission too...

```
ls -la
chown rethinkdb.rethinkdb -R $PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert
chmod 644 $PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert/*
chmod 600 $PATH_WD/rethinkdb_cert/privkey.pem
```